# How to create Expression<Func<object>> from property name

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

I want to create an expression like this:

```
public class Entity
{        
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
}

Entity alias = null;
Expression<Func<object>> target = () => alias.Id;//have to be created from "Id"
```

My question is how to create `Expression<Func<object>> target` programaticaly having string with property name("Id" in this example).

Comment: Have you tried a reflection based factory?

Comment: Have a look at [Expression trees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654263.aspx).

Comment: Is an `Expression<Func<object>>` what you want? The `Entity` is coming from your application (not an input to the expression) and its `Id` property is a `long` not an `object`.
Would an `Expression<Func<Entity, long>>` be more useful?
For example: 
`Expression<Func<Entity, long>> target = a => a.Id;`

Comment: I do want use Expression trees but I only start working with them

Comment: why not simply use `nameof(Entity.Id)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving Property name from lambda expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I hope, i have finally understood, what do you need :)

I suggest to create such extension method:

```
public static class EntityExtensions
{
    public static Expression<Func<object>> ToExpression(this Entity entity, string property)
    {
        var constant = Expression.Constant(entity);
        var memberExpression = Expression.Property(constant, property);     
        Expression convertExpr = Expression.Convert(memberExpression, typeof(object));
        var expression = Expression.Lambda(convertExpr);

        return (Expression<Func<object>>)expression;
    }
}
```

and than call it this way:

```
var entity = new Entity { Id = 4711 };
var expression = entity.ToExpression("Id");
var result = expression.Compile().DynamicInvoke();
```

You have to give entity as a parameter.

*People, who downvote accepted answer, could explain, what the probem it.*

Comment: Thank you, but I really need `Expression<Func<object>>` because I want to pass it to another method which can accept only `Expression<Func<object>>`(it's WithAlias method from NHibernate)

Comment: Sorry, but I need not `Expression<Func<Entity, object>>` but `Expression<Func<object>>`. Just like this: `() => alias.Id`

Comment: It this is the desired method, you could replace `this Entity entity` with `this T source` to make this method available on all kind of objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly what I need!